# Get string between two characters occurring many times in a line

Tags: regex, grep

I am trying to extract a single string out of a line having many segments in a key-value order, but I don't get it as it matches much more than I want to.

This is my example line:

```
|SEGA~1~MAGIC~DESCRIPTION~~~M~TEST~|SEGB~34~12.11.2011~3~M~O~|SEGC~HELLO~WORLD~|
```

This lines is a kind concatenation of many segments into one line. Now I want to extract the the string at index 2 in the segment starting with SEGA.
So what I do is grep for this:

```
egrep -o 'SEGA(.*?)\~\|'
```

But it gives me the whole line, sometimes it gives me only the segment I am looking for. With the match I would split that segment by using the ~ character and take the third one.
Since I use .*? with the question mark I expected egrep to only match the content between SEGA and the very first occurrence of ~| which is right before SEGB and not the one at the end of SEGC or SEGB.

How can I tell grep to search for SEGA and give the whole content starting right after SEGA until THE VERY FIRST occurrence of ~|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `-P`(--perl-regexp) option in grep:

```
grep -oP '(?<=SEGA).*?(?=~\|)' file
```

If you want to include the trailing `~|`, please remove the lookahead `(?=...)`.

I think `.*?` (lazy) does not exit in egrep.

Comment: Ok seems that -P option helped me out. Because i had the same regex used for grep but it terminated without matches. Now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you break the line into lines on `|` and then grep from those:

```
$ echo "|SEGA~1~MAGIC~DESCRIPTION~~~M~TEST~|SEGB~34~12.11.2011~3~M~O~|SEGC~HELLO~WORLD~|" | sed -e 's/|/\n/g' | grep ^SEGA
SEGA~1~MAGIC~DESCRIPTION~~~M~TEST~
```